# How to continue bake fluid simulation in blender 2.80

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, fluid-simulation, baking

I have baked a fluid simulation which baked till 151th frame out of 240 frames, Now I want to continue the bake from 151th frame. Can we do that in 2.80 Blender

Answer (score 0):

If you have baked it, just go to physics properties tab and tap on 'Resume'.

[image]